# React router : blank page after pushstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

We have a custom JS framework for an internal portal and I'm trying to reach a React application using states.

In my portal, on the menu, i have the following code :

```
<a onclick="history.pushState(null, 'newstate', '/persons');">Persons</a>
```

We listen on the state change event thanks to `window.onpopstate`.
When It happens, we attach the JS application related to the new state.

So when I click, It generates the following url :

```
http://localhost:3000/persons
```

Thanks to this code, as my React app is included in the "script" tag and as we detected state change, we attach the React app to the DOM.
Here is how the router is defined in the freshly imported React App:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import PersonsList from './PersonsList';
import Error from './Error'
import Person from './Person'

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" strict={false} component={PersonsList}/>
            <Route path="/persons/:id" component={Person}/>
            <Route component={Error}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

The first route works as from the portal's main menu when It fires the `pushState` function, the React applications shows and then the first defined Route runs.

The problem is that in the `PersonsList`, when I try to reach the `/persons/:id` route, I get a blank page.

Here is the code I use for redirection in the PersonsList component :

```
static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object
};

handleRedirection = (aPerson) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/persons/${aPerson.id}`);
}

...

{this.state.persons.map(aPerson => (
    <React.Fragment key={aPerson.id}>
        <div className="row" onClick={this.handleRedirection.bind(this,aPerson)}>
```

**Edit 1:**
Following the first comment, I put the `exact` keyword in the route. But I still get a blank page.

Here is the `Person` component :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Person extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        match: PropTypes.object 
    };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('the selected person : ' + this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>A person</div>
        )
    }
}


export default withRouter(Person);
```

I can see the `console.log` output but no rendering of the `<div>A person</div>`.

**Question** 
Why the second route returns a blank content ?

Comment: Your first `Route` with `path="/"` will always match, so no other `Route` after that one in the `Switch` will be able to render. Have you tried adding the `exact` prop? `<Route path="/" exact component={PersonsList} />`

Comment: @Tholle thanks for your comment. Please see my edit.

Comment: You have written `<Route path="/persons/:id" strict={Person}/>`. Could you try changing `strict` to `component`?

Comment: @Tholle thanks. It was just a typo as I changed the original definitions. I edited the post and still have the problem : blank page but the component's controller is invoked.